# Como diminuir o espaçamento entre as divs do bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, div

Boa tarde! Estou com uma dúvida/problema/problema.
Estou usando o bootstrap para fazer um layout, mas o espaçamento entre as divs é muito grande, queria que fosse menor... tem como?

***é assim que as divs ficam, super afastadas***

[image: é assim que as divs ficam, super afastadas]

***Mas queria que ficassem assim.***

[image]

Obrigada por qualquer ajuda e tenham um ótimo dia!

Comment: Qual versão do Bootstrap?

Comment: @hugocsl versão 3

Answer (score 1):

No Bootstrap 3 todas as colunas têm um `padding` nas laterais de 15px para cada lado.

```
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Basta alterar esse valor nos `padding`s para "estreitar" esse espaço entre uma coluna e outra.

Aqui tem a documentação oficial e vc pode conferir o valor default do "gutter" padrão https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options

**Exemplo com o padding ajustado, diminui do padrão 15px de cada lado para 6px de cada lado**

```css
div[class^="col-"] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding-left: 6px !important;
    padding-right: 6px !important;
}
.bg {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="bg">1</div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="bg">2</div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="bg">3</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pela resposta, Hugo! Mas ainda continuo com uma duvida, fiz o que vc disse e ficou o espaço entre elas como esperava, porém ficou um espaço nas laterais também. Não sei se deu para entender bem, por isso envio um print https://i.imgur.com/NFCeL2x.png 
Desculpe qualquer erro, sou nova na area. 
 Você sabe me dizer se esse "problema" com os paddings some na versão 4?

Comment: @Lia lia acabei de ver que eu tinha escrito `<row>`, mas deveria ser `<div class="row">`, então tira onde está escrito ROW e coloca  `<div class="row">` para ver como fica

Comment: Se o erro continuar vou te pedir para editar sua pergunta e colocar o código inteiro na pergunta... inclusive com o CSS extra que estiver usando... repare que a forma que fiz tb é apenas para fins didáticos com "[class^="col-"]" o ideal seria vc tirar esse padding apenas onde vc realmente precisa...